# The best way to refer to the intended noun in the mentioned sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, pronouns, reference

> This research is supposed to examine how the sociology of a relation
>   affects **its** ethics.

In the above sentence I want "its" to refer to "a relation", but the way the sentence is constructed it sounds as if "its" can also refer to "the sociology of a relation". Is there any way I can avoid this ambiguity?

Comment: Why not just say "...how the sociology of a relation affects  **that relation's** ethics"?

Comment: What is "the sociology of a relation"

Comment: @Lambie Do you have to ask that?! This is just a sample sentence. It could be anything else. The model is: How the X of p affects its Y.

Comment: How the sociology of urban politics reflects its ethics. Now, there's a title. But, that means that sociology has ethics. Hmm. How the thinkers of Classical Greece affected its citizens. The its goes back to the entire phrase.

Comment: Is this **really** "just a sample sentence," as you claim? It looks more like a sentence from a research paper you are in the midst of authoring. That's not prohibited, of course, but it might be better to use simpler examples that are _true_ "sample sentences" – especially if you don't want to be asked questions about meaning. Deeper, more confusing sentences can be harder to analyze.